# Can't delete temporary object

Tags: c++, pointers, delete-operator

I'm resizing and array of objects.  I made a temp object but when I don't delete it Valgrind shows memory leaks and an error.  Deleting it causes a segfault.  Just wondering what Valgrind is complaining about...

```
void Obj::resize()
{
  Obj *temp = new Obj[size * 2];   //<-- line 92
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    temp[i] = objarray[i];
  delete [] objarray;
  objarray = temp;
  size *= 2;
  //delete temp;   //<-- causes segfault
  //delete [] temp;  // also segfaults, tried them both just in case :\
}
```

Here's the Valgrind report:

```
==9292== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9292==     in use at exit: 21,484 bytes in 799 blocks
==9292==   total heap usage: 3,528 allocs, 2,729 frees, 91,789 bytes allocated
==9292==
==9292== 21,484 (2,644 direct, 18,840 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4 of 4
==9292==    at 0x4008409: operator new[](unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:357)
==9292==    by 0x804AC7E: MyClass::resize() (file.cpp:92)
==9292==    by 0x804AC34: MyClass::add(int, int) (file.cpp:82)
==9292==    by 0x804AAE6: getline(std::istream&, MyClass&) (file.cpp:66)
==9292==    by 0x8049772: main (otherfile.cpp:39)
==9292==
==9292== LEAK SUMMARY:
==9292==    definitely lost: 2,644 bytes in 1 blocks
==9292==    indirectly lost: 18,840 bytes in 798 blocks
==9292==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9292==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9292==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9292==
==9292== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9292== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I'm not too good with gdb, but got this backtrace:

```
    (gdb) run
Starting program: 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x46ed40e3 in free () from /lib/libc.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.15-58.fc17.i686 libgcc-4.7.2-2.fc17.i686 libstdc++-4.7.2-2.fc17.i686
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x46ed40e3 in free () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x4742dba0 in operator delete(void*) () from /lib/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x0804ad68 in MyClass::resize (this=0xbffff28c) at file.cpp:98
#3  0x0804ac35 in MyClass::add (this=0xbffff28c, month=10, day=31)
    at file.cpp:82
#4  0x0804aae7 in getline (input=..., a=...) at file.cpp:66
#5  0x08049773 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff344) at otherfile.cpp:39
(gdb)
```

I think that deleting this is bad, because it should just leave the pointer dangling, so it doesn't surprise me that I get a segfault. Still, why would it then cause memory problems?  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why would you delete `temp`? **You shouldn't**. delete doesn't free the pointer but what it points to. If you delete `temp` you delete your `objarray` too (*what it points to*).

Comment: Yes, I realize that.  What I'm wondering is why does it still create a memory issue?

Comment: The segfault might be caused by something else. You see the effect there. But the cause might be in add...

Comment: Probably double delete in your destructor.

Comment: What does `Obj` do?  Does it correctly support copy and assignment, for example?

Comment: If the failure occurs inside `resize`, then it's because the *previous* call to resize left a dangling pointer in `objarray`, and the second call tried to delete that dangling pointer.

Comment: @MArk to understand valgrind message refer to this link http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html . And stop deleting temp as people suggested here

Comment: @MArk for memory leak i think you are just forgot deallocating obj array inside destructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you can't delete it there since you've assigned it to `objarray` to be used later.

Most likely, you're not deleting `objarray` in the destructor; or some other function is reassigning it without deleting the old array first.

I would use `std::vector` rather than a hand-crafted array, to take care of deallocation for me.

Comment: Thank you.  As you (and others) suggested, I was neglecting to utilize the destructor correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Explicit `delete` (or `delete[]`) should only be needed in very low-level library code.  Everywhere else you should use smart pointers instead.

Here's a better approach that is (IMO) easier to understand:

```
std::unique_ptr<Obj[]> temp(new Obj[size * 2]);

// copy stuff from objarray to temp

swap(objarray, temp);
```

That's it.  The `unique_ptr` destructor will free the old `objarray` buffer if the swap succeeded.  And if an exception was thrown during the copy, it will free the new temporary buffer.  In either case `objarray` (which should also be `std::unique_ptr<Obj[]>`) is left with a valid buffer.

Comment: The use of `std::unique_ptr` is probably the simplest solution here, but I don't think that `swap` will work; both arguments of `swap` have to have the same type.  (In general, of course: he's basically reimplementing `std::vector`.  And doing this correctly in the general case---e.g. if `Obj` doesn't support default construction, is non-trivial.)

Comment: @James: Naturally `objarray` should also be a `unique_ptr<Obj[]>`... there's no reason for it to be a raw pointer either.

Comment: @Sarien: It does just swap the pointers.  So that now `temp` owns the old buffer which needs to be destroyed, and does so when it goes out of scope at the closing brace of `resize`.

Comment: Sorry, deleted my comment when I got it. Thanks for the explanation! :)

Comment: @BenVoigt Best to say so, then.  (I'd attack the problem differently.  But then, the only time I'd attack it at all is if I were implementing `std::vector` in the standard library.  Which means supporting objects without default destructors, which means `new[]` can't be used, which means `delete[]` can't be used, which means that `unique_ptr` can't be used, at least with the default deleter.)

Comment: @James: There are a few possible reasons I can think for using `unique_ptr<T[]>{new T[]}` instead of `std::vector`.  For example, if I wanted to use a different algorithm for buffer growth, or report some statistics on how often I needed to resize.  But certainly just using `std::vector` is by far the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the SECOND (or later) time you call `resize`, then this is a very likely scenario, because you are trying to `delete` on a heap that has already had a `double delete` since the `temp` was already deleted, and now all your `objArray` writes have gone into a lump of memory that belongs to the heap-management, not to your code.

All sorts of other potential issues may also happen here, such as the memory is now being used for some OTHER object, and it's writing things into the heap memory that you then use as objArray.

You shouldn't delete `temp` where you are trying to do so. Just don't.